# php cli output, prevent header information

Tags: php, command-line-interface

server: Red Hat 4.4.7-18

When i launch php script with cli:
`php myscript.php >> my.log`

before the output 'echo', there is 2 more lines in the my.log file:

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.33 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

How to prevent this output ?
Tanks a lot and sory for my english.

Comment: I believe RedHat uses different binaries for the CLI interface, try `php-cli myscript.php` instead. (The one you're using is for CGI, which is assumed to be sent to a browser.)

Comment: I think you might also be able to use the `-q` switch: `php -q myscript.php`. (I'm not 100% sure about either of these methods, but it should be easy for you to test them.)

Comment: I always use the `-f` flag....

Comment: Tanks, using php-cli don't send header !

Answer (score 0):

Some servers do this by default with their environment setup but not all. So use

```
php -q ...
```

It's best to set this up in your home directory, in the default config file for your environment.  For example, if using the ever popular Bash, it would be something like

```
alias php='/usr/local/php80/bin/php -q'
```